# How to create a command to incrementally increase redshift's color temperature?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, redshift

`redshift` is a package that enables blue light filter, so people can avoid eye strain.

This software is pretty good, but it lacks controls to adjust the filter color temperature, **incrementally**: no sliders, buttons or commands.

When I say "incrementally", what I mean is that I need a command to set color temperature according to the previous value. The package `xbacklight` has a good example:

```
xbacklight +10 #increases monitor brightness by 10%
```

or...

```
xbacklight -10 #decreases monitor brightness by 10%
```

Hence, if brightness value was 70%: now, it would become 60%.

What I need is a command like this:

```
temperature +10 #increases color temperature by 10%
```

---

#### what redshift already provides

With `redshift`, you can manually set color temperature like this:

```
redshift -O 3000K
```

Although, there's no built-in way to increase this value by 10%.

Therefore, if you need to increase the value, you  need to do this:

```
redshift -x #reset the previous value
redshift -O 3300K
```

Notice that: not only I had to calculate the new value manually, I also had to reset the previous value, first.

---

#### why do I need to do this

I study all day, using my laptop. So, I need to have blue light filter on, in order to save my eyes and be more productive.

I have some some ideas on how to make a simple shell script that could do this, but I have no idea how I would go and store the previous value variable or where to store this kinda script properly.

Comment: Did you know you can give Redshift your latitude and longitude so that it automatically and incrementally changes the display? See `-l` for that and `-t` to set the temperature interval.

Comment: @Quasímodo Yes. Although, I need to adjust these parameters manually because not always the color temperature set automatically is enough to relax my eyes.

Comment: You can also set the color temperature minimum and maximum.

Comment: @l0b0 what if I store a variable in `.profile`, so everytime I need to increment the old color temperature value I can use it from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and made a simple package called [tempcolor](https://github.com/entrywayaudibly/tempcolor).

Now, I'm able to even create keyboard shortcuts to change color temperature incrementally.

### install

- place the contents of the repo wherever you want to;
- make `tempcolor` executable: `chmod +x ./tempcolor`;
- feel free to create a symbolic link for `tempcolor`.

  - be it in `/usr/bin`;
  - or be it in `$HOME/.local/bin`.

#### usage

**incrementally change color temperature**

- `tempcolor -inc <percent_value>`
- `tempcolor -dec <percent_value>`

**reset color temperature (turn off)**

- `tempcolor -x`

**set value using one shot mode (-O)**

- `tempcolor <value>`